# Blank space at end of page

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

#### Background

A subreport with a column title and a detail section both set to 20px high.

When the subreport record displays on the main report, the subreport prints as expected until when it reaches at the bottom of the page.

Then the subreport prints just the column header and left blank space, then again starts on new page with column header and its detail.

#### Question

So, would you make it either print the whole subreport on same page, or start whole report from new page?

#### Master Report JRXML

http://pastebin.com/V2HRPWVL

Image of the problem faces

[image]

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: Please post a couple of images, if possible, showing the behaviour your are seeing. Use http://imgur.com/. Also consider using http://pastebin.com/ for large code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set the `Split Type` of related **`band`** to `Prevent`. (Might be `detail band`)

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly as i set splitType of detail band to prevent.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to delete the last blank page that appears in the report, is eliminating the pagination of the report

Comment: thank you for your answer , but i have already solved the issue 2 years ago.

Comment: But there might be other people with this issue rignt now. For example, me.

Comment: Or me...almost three years after that.   Unfortunately...when I set the report to ignore pagination and try to run it as PDF it is blank.  It runs fine as JAVA or HTML.   I am using JasperReports Studio 5.62. I have a text field and sub-report in the Detail band and it works like a charm...except it prints a blank page at the end.  Anyone still looking at this topic have an idea?  I may create a new question...

Comment: Setting "Ignore Pagination" on the report did the trick for me, thanks!